# Querying Instagram photos and data using Java API

Tags: java, instagram, instagram-api

I am looking for a Java API to query Instagram images based on a given coordinate or bounding box. I will appreciate if someone can tell me if there is any such JAVA API exists?

TIA

Comment: I don't think Instagram allow that, checkout their endpoints https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/

Comment: not sure what you're after is allowed from the api but a java lib for using the api is https://github.com/sachin-handiekar/jInstagram

Comment: For querying information (not making posts/ putting likes or comments) the official Instagram API is the best. https://www.instagram.com/developer/
However, here is one more lib: https://github.com/brunocvcunha/instagram4j

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by first searching for Instagram locations by geo coordinates using  their /locations/search endpoint, and then pull the medias for each searched location using endpoint /locations/{location-id}/media/recent.

All Instagram APIs require authentication which means you would have to go through the process of creating an Instagram App and authorizing the app to access your account to get an Auth token. More details are available at https://www.instagram.com/developer/

The Java API 'jInstagram' mentioned by @Thanos is decent one to start with but it is not actively maintained and you still need all the App creation and authentication processes anyway. If you are doing serious development, it worth to write your Java program to access the Instagram endpoints directly. You can use Scrible to negotiate the OAuth process.